# Installing noip via sh script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script

I have this script:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/
make install <<END_SCRIPT
Username
password
30
N
END_SCRIPT
```

According to [this guide](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) it should install Noip DUC (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, go to the section for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). When it gets to make install part, I tried to configure it so it would automatically enter all need information ("username", "password", "update interval", and "do you wish to run something after install (Y/N)?").

The install goes fine until I get to the configuration part.
This is the last line of the output:

`Enter-username  Enter-password-for-Username  _`

(underscore is the cursor)

The program then just hangs ther and accepts no input.

This is how it looks like when you do it manually (more or less, I didn't copy preset printed strings to the letter):

```
Enter-username Username
Enter-password-for-Username password
Enter-interval 30
Question(Y/N)? N

Install done
```

Now, I know the Username was entered properly because it prints it out when requesting password. However, when it comes to the password part, it just hangs there. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to do this using expect - I think it will be easier. ref.: http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expect` program is designed exactly for this situation.  To use it with the noip client, adjust your script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/

/usr/bin/expect <<END_SCRIPT
spawn make install
expect "Please enter the login/email*" { send "Username\r" }
expect "Please enter the password for user*" { send "password\r" }
expect "Please enter an update interval*" { send "30\r" }
expect "Do you wish to run something at successful update*" {send "N\r" }
END_SCRIPT
```